# How use $TIGER from the "Modern Compiler Implementation in C" book?

Tags: c, compiler-construction

I'm learning compiler construction following the book *Modern Compiler Implementation in C*. In the introduction there is a "PROGRAM STRAIGHT-LINE PROGRAM INTERPRETER", which it said is "available in the directory `$TIGER/chap1`", so I downloaded the TIGER compiler from https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~appel/modern/c/project.html.

In the `chap1` directory, there some files:

```
chap1$ ls
1.png    makefile prog1.h  slp.h    util.h
main.c   prog1.c  slp.c    util.c
```

So I execute make command in the 'chap1' directory , but it shows an error:

```
chap1$ make
cc -g -c main.c
cc -g -c prog1.c
cc -g -c slp.c
cc -g -c util.c
cc -g main.o prog1.o slp.o util.o
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [a.out] Error 1
```

Here is the `makefile`:

```
a.out: main.o prog1.o slp.o util.o
    cc -g main.o prog1.o slp.o util.o

main.o: main.c slp.h util.h
    cc -g -c main.c

prog1.o: prog1.c slp.h util.h
    cc -g -c prog1.c

slp.o: slp.c slp.h util.h
    cc -g -c slp.c

util.o: util.c util.h
    cc -g -c util.c

clean: 
    rm -f a.out util.o prog1.o slp.o main.o
```

It seems the `chap1` directory is a complete project, but I don't know what the function of `chap1` directory in TIGER compiler and how to use it.

Comment: Please correct the formatting in your post.  Use the information on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in order to see how.

Comment: `main.c` contains this comment: `/* This file is intentionally empty.  You should fill it in with your solution to the programming exercise. */`. That is what you should do. The function of the `chap1` directory is to give you the basis to do the exercises. The function of the exercises is to help you learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In file main.c, there is not main function. Please provide it in this file. Here is the template:

```
#include "util.h"
#include "slp.h"
#include "prog1.h"

int main()
{
   A_stm stm = prog();

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: yes, empirically, this is correct, but I want to know the specific function of chap1 directory.

Comment: @lslboy prog1.c implemented the function A_stm prog(void). So in the main function, you can call this function and extract much infomation in A_stm. Please include util.h , slp.h prog1.h in main.c